# Alter access database with dao or oledb

Tags: c#, sql, database, ms-access

I want to use this query to close all active connections to an Access database:

```
ALTER DATABASE YourDatabaseName SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
```

But when I run this query, I get different errors depending on the engine. Apparently I am using the wrong methods or not calling them correctly. What do I need to change?

DAO:

```
public static void KillDbWithDAO()
{
    string sql = "ALTER DATABASE TrafficData SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE";
    var dbengine = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.DBEngine();
    var con = dbengine.OpenDatabase(@"C:\dev\TrafficData\Db\TrafficData.accdb");
    con.Execute(sql);
}

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Invalid SQL statement; expected 'DELETE', 'INSERT', 'PROCEDURE', 'SELECT', or 'UPDATE'.'
```

OleDbConnection:

```
public static void KillDbWithOleDb()
{
    string sql = "ALTER DATABASE TrafficData SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE";
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\dev\TrafficData\Db\TrafficData.accdb");
    con.Open();
    OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand(sql, con);
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Invalid SQL syntax - expected token: Password.'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps I am wrong but I don't think you can use these statements for an ms-access database.

Comment: An Access database is just a file. If you want to remove locks to that file, you need to do that from the file server (assuming it's on a network share) but it may lead to corruption. That query is not valid Access SQL, nor is there an equivalent Access SQL query to accomplish something like this. If you control the clients, you can have them poll something (e.g. a special file, a table, a database property) and have them disconnect when that gets changed to a special value. If not, you're all out of luck.